# ActiveScaffold alike Admin for Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, code-generation, admin, activescaffold

I need an admin interface for my spring-struts-hibernate application. an interface for creating, updating, and deleting objects. In Rails there's ActiveScaffold. Does something like an admin generator exist in the Java world? For Spring?

Handcoding all this is just such a pain in the arm. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait,are you looking for a data-generator or a CRUD classes generator?

Comment: I'm confused... you want a code generator, not an admin tool, yes? Your question talks about the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo)?

Answer (score 1):

Also on the side look at OpenXava. You would be amazed by the development speed there.